# Accessing parent through unsaved child association (has_many through)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have payments with one transaction associated with each payment. The transactions can be associated with payments, deposits, etc. so I need a :through relation.

The Payment class:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payment_transactions
  has_many :transactions, :through => :payment_transactions
end
```

And the Transaction class:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :payment_transaction, :inverse_of => :transaction
  has_one :payment, :through => :payment_transaction
end
```

And finally the PaymentTransaction class:

```
class PaymentTransaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :payment
  belongs_to :transaction
end
```

When adding the transaction to the payment I would like to be able to access the parent information (the payment attributes) from within the newly created transaction:

```
2.1.0 :001 > p = Payment.new
 => #<Payment id: nil, state: "new", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
2.1.0 :002 > p.save
 => true
2.1.0 :003 > p.transactions.build()
 => #<Transaction id: nil, myid: nil, parent_class_is: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
2.1.0 :004 > p.transactions.first.payment
 => nil
```

I am looking for a way to access the payment from the newly created transaction associated with the payment - but no luck. The payment is saved, however the transaction is still not committed to the database. Only when the payment is saved and the associated transaction is stored I get access to the parent object:

```
2.1.0 :005 > p.save
2.1.0 :008 > p.reload
2.1.0 :009 > p.transactions.first.payment
=> #<Payment id: 3, state: "new", created_at: "2014-01-28 09:23:13", updated_at: "2014-01-28 09:23:13">
```

Using the :inverse_of is not possible with :through associations. :(

---

Edit 1:

Tried to access the parent via a proxy association:

app/concerns/transaction_proxy.rb

```
module TransactionProxy

  private

  def my_owner
    proxy_association.owner
  end

end
```

The payment model:

```
has_many :payment_transactions
has_many :transactions, -> { extending TransactionProxy }, :through => :payment_transactions
```

Loading the payment:

```
2.1.0 :006 > p = Payment.first
  Payment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "payments".* FROM "payments" ORDER BY "payments"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<Payment id: 1, state: "new", created_at: "2014-01-28 12:31:11", updated_at: "2014-01-28 12:31:11">
```

Setting the transaction:

```
2.1.0 :007 > p.transactions.build()
 => #<Transaction id: nil, myid: nil, parent_class_is: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Query the transaction:

```
2.1.0 :005 > p.transactions.first
 => #<Transaction id: nil, myid: nil, parent_class_is: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

2.1.0 :007 > p.transactions.first.payment
 => nil
```

and trying to use the proxy:

```
2.1.0 :006 > p.transactions.first.my_owner
NoMethodError: undefined method `my_owner' for #<Transaction:0x00000103e44450>
```

I assume that the .my_owner on a transaction should return the owner (payment) of that transaction?

Comment: can you add a little context to why - because there's probably an alternative simpler solution than doing what you're asking...

Comment: The transaction needs to pull some information from the parent object (a description) and store that in an attribute in the transaction. Also if the transaction got a payment it should perform certain business logic (again a transaction can belong to a payment, a deposit, etc.)

Comment: You could wrap it in a DB transaction, that will enable you to do the save and still roll everything back if needed

Comment: Before you save p again: What does p.transactions.first.payment_transaction.inspect return?

Comment: p.transactions.first.payment_transaction.inspec returns nil - so the association through the payment_transactions table is not defined yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks confusing to me!

---

**Polymorphic**

I think you'd benefit from a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) on the transactions model. This will allow your transactions to belong to either `payments`, `deposits` or any model

Your use of a `through` relation means `transactions` can only be associated with `payments` *and* transaction & payment objects have to be created before you can associate them:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :transactable, polymorphic: true
end

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions, as: :transactable
end

class Deposit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions, as: :transactable
end

class Reward < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions, as: :transactable
end
```

[image: Polymorphic Association]

---

**Extrabutes**

If you want to keep your `has_many :through` association, you can use the [`ActiveRecord Association Extensions`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions) `proxy_association` object to retrieve the data you need

We made a script to extra join-table data, which you'll be able to adapt to pull child-object attributes:

```
#app/models/concerns/image_caption.rb
module ImageCaption

        #Load
        def load
      captions.each do |caption|
              proxy_association.target << caption
      end
        end

        #Private
        private

        #Captions
        def captions
                return_array = []
                through_collection.each_with_index do |through,i|
                        associate = through.send(reflection_name)
                        associate.assign_attributes({caption: items[i]})
                        return_array.concat Array.new(1).fill( associate )
                end
                return_array
        end

        #######################
        #      Variables      #
        #######################

        #Association
        def reflection_name
                proxy_association.source_reflection.name
        end

        #Foreign Key
        def through_source_key
                proxy_association.reflection.source_reflection.foreign_key
        end

        #Primary Key
        def through_primary_key
                proxy_association.reflection.through_reflection.active_record_primary_key
        end

        #Through Name
        def through_name
                proxy_association.reflection.through_reflection.name
        end

        #Through
        def through_collection
                proxy_association.owner.send through_name
        end

        #Captions
        def items
                through_collection.map(&:caption)
        end

        #Target
        def target_collection
                #load_target
                proxy_association.target
        end

end

#app/models/message.rb
has_many :image_messages
has_many :images, through: :image_messages, extend: ImageCaption
```

If you'd like me to modify this code for you, please ask in the comments!

Comment: Polymorphic associations isn't an option for us. Even though we can do it with Postgres it's kind of a messy hack and I prefer to use the :through method to keep our database model clean. I will have a look at the proxy_association.

Comment: I think that you didn't understand my initial post - It is not the child objects that I am interested in - it is accessing the parent object attributes from the child before the child is saved to the database that I am interested in.

Comment: You'll be able to do it with `proxy_association` - you'll have to use `proxy_association.owner`

Comment: You'll not get any data out of the proxy_association, it's just a reference object. You'll have to use something like `proxy_association.owner.send(:x)` I think

Comment: If you go into chat, I can help -- I spent a week making our `image_caption` code, so might be able to give you some further ideas

Comment: The my_owner method is not defined for the transaction even though it is defined in the concerns file. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46234/discussion-between-lasse-laursen-and-rich-peck)